# How do I distinguish between "more" and "further"?

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs, adjectives

Can you think of any situation in which you might find the following words interchangeable?

- more
- further

Additionally, I am wondering what is the difference between these two expressions:

- a **further** edition of this book
- **another** edition of this book

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's talk about their interchangeability. There are some contexts where the two words could be used to mean "additional"; however, I think there seems to be a subtle difference in meaning when the word *further* is used:

> The summit ended without any **more** talks.
>   The summit ended without any **further** talks.
>
> I could not have run any **further**.
>   I could not have run any **more**.

In the case of the summit meeting, the word *further* hints that talks might have helped two sides come closer to an agreement. That's because one meaning of *further* is:

> **further** (*adv*.) at or to a more advanced, successful, or desirable stage
>   <sub>(from NOAD)</sub>

In the case of the tired runner, *any further* suggests a greater distance, while *any more* suggests a longer time. While those meanings overlap, I think *further* might be a better word for a runner dropping out of a marathon, while *more* might be a better word for someone working out on a treadmill. That's because *further* also means:

> **further** (*adv*.) by a greater distance, or for a longer way
>   <sub>(from NOAD)</sub>

---

As for the book, I think the best way to describe the latest edition of a book is:

> a **new** edition of the book

You might use *another* when comparing two different editions of the same book:

> I bought a new copy of *A Study in Scarlet*.
>   *Really? I thought you already owned that book*.
>   I do, but this was **another edition**.

It's harder to use *further*, because, in the context of publishing, I would interpret *further* to mean:

> **further** (*adj*.) additional to what already exists or has already taken place or been done
>   <sub>(from NOAD)</sub>

However, I suppose we could:

> The publisher has indicated a reluctance to print any **further editions** of this book.

In that last sentence, the adjectives *new* or *more* could work in place of *further*.